# Getting Bus error: 10 when I run my C code

Tags: c

I'm writing a function in C to make my web server display the directory listing as an HTML document. When I run make, everything seems to compile fine, but when I run the file, I keep getting bus error:10. Thank you for all of your help!

This is the HTML template that I want to write into the socket id to display when I run my file on localhost:3000 (or localhost:8000):

```
<ul>
<li><a href='./'>.</a></li>
<li><a href='../'>..</a></li>
<li><a href='.DS_Store'>.DS_Store</a></li>
<li><a href='resume/'>resume</a></li>
<li><a href='lolcode.html'>lolcode.html</a></li>
<li><a href='ybruf.pid'>ybruf.pid</a></li>
</ul>
```

This is my code for this function:

```
static bool process_dir(int sock_id, char *doc)
{
  // Open the directory for reading
  DIR *dir = opendir(doc);

  /* if the dir failed to open */
  if (dir == NULL)
  {
    syslog(LOG_ERR, "opendir(): %s", strerror(errno));
    write_http_header(sock_id, PROTO "404 File Not Found",
                      "File Not Found");
    return false;
  }

  // Write the header - we seem to be ok
  // Technically, this is not correct. We must first fully read the direct
  /* successfull open the dir */
  write_http_header(sock_id, PROTO "200 OK", NULL);

  // Define the template
  struct dirent *dirp;
  dirp = readdir(dir);
  char dirp_name[1024]; // if it is a diretory then dirp_name will have / 
  char *ul_open = "<ul>\n";
  char *ul_close = "</ul>";
  write(sock_id, ul_open, strlen(ul_open));

  char *li_open = "<li><a href='";
  char *li_middle = "'>";
  char *li_close = "</a></li>\n";

  while (dirp != NULL)
  {
    // if it's a file, then just need to get the name
    // for example: resume.html
    strcpy(dirp_name, dirp->d_name);

    if (dirp->d_type == DT_DIR)
    {
      // if it's a directory then need to have / at the end
      // for example: resume/
      strcat(dirp_name, "/");
    }
   
    // for example: <li><a href='resume/'>resume</a></ li>
   
    write(sock_id, li_open, strlen(li_open));
    write(sock_id, dirp_name, strlen(dirp_name));
    write(sock_id, li_middle, strlen(li_middle));
    write(sock_id, dirp->d_name, dirp->d_namlen);
    write(sock_id, li_close, strlen(li_close));

    dirp = readdir(dir);
  }
  write(sock_id, ul_close, strlen(ul_close));

  errno = 0; // Assume no errors
  closedir(dir);

  if (errno)
  {
    // Too late to complain!
    syslog(LOG_ERR, "%s", strerror(errno));
  }

  return errno == 0;
}
```

Comment: can we have a complete program that we can test please

Comment: one obvious error is that if opendir fails you still carry on processing as if it worked

Comment: @pm100 I'm not sure if I can share the whole complete program without my professor's permission. But thank you for your comment, I noticed that I forgot to return false if opendir failed. I just edited the code with the return false.

Comment: ok, well fix the error i mentioned. Then can you run it under a debugger so that at least you get to know which line is failing - compile with debug too